# How can I make a class decorator not break isinstance function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, singleton, decorator

I'm creating a singleton decorator for tests, but when I ask if an object is of instance of the original class it returns false.

In the example I'm decorating a counter class to create a singleton, so every time if I get the value it returns the next number no matter what instance of the object calls it.
the code pretty much works but the function isinstance seems to break, I tried using functools.update_wrapper but I don't know if I can get isinstance function to recognize Singleton as Counter (in the following code) as long as when I ask for Counter the code actually returns Singleton.

## decorator

```
def singleton(Class):

    class Singleton:
        __instance = None

        def __new__(cls):
            if not Singleton.__instance:
                Singleton.__instance = Class()

            return Singleton.__instance

    #update_wrapper(Singleton, Class, 
    #    assigned=('__module__', '__name__', '__qualname__', '__doc__', '__annotation__'), 
    #    updated=()) #doesn't seems to work
    return Singleton
```

## decorated class

```
@singleton
class Counter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = -1
        self.__limit = 6

    @property
    def value(self):
        self.__value = (self.__value + 1) % self.limit
        return self.__value

    @property
    def limit(self):
        return self.__limit

    @limit.setter
    def limit(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise ValueError('value must be an int.')

        self.__limit = value

    def reset(self):
        self.__value = -1

    def __iter__(self):
        for _ in range(self.limit):
            yield self.value

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self,a,b,c):
        pass
```

## test

```
counter = Counter()
counter.limit = 7
counter.reset()
[counter.value for _ in range(2)]

with Counter() as cnt:
    print([cnt.value for _ in range(10)]) #1

print([counter.value for _ in range(5)]) #2
print([val for val in Counter()]) #3

print(Counter) #4
print(type(counter)) #5 
print(isinstance(counter, Counter)) #6
```

output:

```
#1 - [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
#2 - [5, 6, 0, 1, 2]
#3 - [3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2]
#4 - <class '__main__.singleton.<locals>.Singleton'>
#5 - <class '__main__.Counter'>
#6 - False
```

(with the update wrapper uncommented)

```
#1 - [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
#2 - [5, 6, 0, 1, 2]
#3 - [3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2]
#4 - <class '__main__.Counter'>
#5 - <class '__main__.Counter'>
#6 - False
```

Comment: On Python 2 it works if you say `class Singleton(Class)`. No idea why it does not work the same on Python 3, but maybe this could lead you there?

Comment: I already tried inheriting from Class, object and various if not all combination of both, any of those seems to work x.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`singleton`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Singleton) class decorator in the [Python Decorator Library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary).

It works because it modifies the existing class (replaces the `__new__()` method) instead of replacing it with a completely separate class as is being done in the code in your question.

```
import functools

# from https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Singleton
def singleton(cls):
    ''' Use class as singleton. '''

    cls.__new_original__ = cls.__new__

    @functools.wraps(cls.__new__)
    def singleton_new(cls, *args, **kw):
        it =  cls.__dict__.get('__it__')
        if it is not None:
            return it

        cls.__it__ = it = cls.__new_original__(cls, *args, **kw)
        it.__init_original__(*args, **kw)
        return it

    cls.__new__ = singleton_new
    cls.__init_original__ = cls.__init__
    cls.__init__ = object.__init__

    return cls
```

With it, I get the following output (note the last line):

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2]
<class '__main__.Counter'>
<class '__main__.Counter'>
True
```

Comment: That seems a smarter idea, but why do this code needs to switch the __init__ function, I noticed that the 3rd line resets if I remove this change. I would like to know why does this happens?

Comment: Kostynha: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "the 3rd line resets".

Comment: I just tought hat it might be because the __init__ is going to be called after __new__ so this is basically avoiding the recall of the original __init__, is that right?

Comment: instead of starting at [3,4,5...] it starts again [0,1,2...]

Comment: @martineau Beat me to it I see (came up with a simpler version of the above). But yes, @Kostynha, you change the `__init__` so that the variables of the counter doesn't reset each time you say `Counter()`.

Comment: Kostynha:  I'm not sure, but think that in your decorator the `__init__()` method of the original class is not even being called — but it is in the decorator library version which calls the original class' `__init__()`.

Comment: @Bendik: If you have a better decorator, post it as an answer — there are many ways to implement singletons.

Comment: @martineau it is because I instantiate the class at "Singleton.__instance = Class()". But I understood the needs of removing the original new and init to made sure that they're also only called once. ty.

Answer (score 1):

Not better than the above, but slightly simpler and easier to remember if you ever need to do this from memory at a later point:

```
def singleton(Class, *initargs, **initkwargs):
    __instance = Class(*initargs, **initkwargs)
    Class.__new__ = lambda *args, **kwargs: __instance
    Class.__init__ = lambda *args, **kwargs: None
    return Class
```

Comment: Indeed, this looks like a good approach. Doesn't do the `functools` wrapping, but that's not a serious limitation IMO — just a minor trade-off I suppose.